# How to concatenate/flatten an object's VALUES to an array?

Tags: arrays, coffeescript, underscore.js, concatenation, key-value

I have the following object:

```
languages:
  english: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  german: [ 4, 5, 6 ]
```

My goal is to get an array of all values of `languages`so that the result looks like `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]`.

This is what I have tried:

```
(word for word in value for key, value of languages)
```

or

```
(word for word in languages[lang] for lang in Object.keys languages)
```

Both methods return a two dimensional array the arrays as first dimension and the values as second dimension

**Is there a way to get the desired result using a one-liner?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631525/concatenating-an-array-of-arrays-in-coffeescript

Answer (score 1):

Use the `concat()` function:

```
[1, 2, 3].concat [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
[].concat (val for key, val of languages)...
```

or

```
Array::concat (val for key, val of languages)...
```

which are the same.

`(val for key, val of languages)` here is the array of all languages arrays to concatenate with one another.

`...` operator is just a shortcut for `java-script` `apply` function.

Comment: Whoops, haven't noticed that the question has already been answered in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it has to be in one line ... but here you have it in 2 LOC

```
result = []
result.splice(result.length, 0, languages[key]...) for key of languages
```